# Chrome loading the contents of a PHP file into a CSS file

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My website loads perfectly on Firefox, but the CSS disappears completely on Chrome (although the html loads).

According to the console, this seems to be because Chrome is loading the contents of index.php into main.css and bannerTest.css like so:

[image: main.css loading incorrectly]

On Firefox, however, it loads the CSS as expected:
[image]

Things I have tried that did not work:

- clearing my history/cache/cookies
- adding text/css to the tags. All this did was make the text render a
  little weirdly on Firefox.
- css and html validation. I fixed all the semi-colons and such. Still doesn't work.

What's the problem? I can't even figure out what steps to take to investigate what's going on more deeply, let alone figure out the problem itself. No errors are printed to the console as far as I can tell.

Here is index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Study</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link href="css/bannerTest.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>

<style>
/**
 * The banner assumes a margin of 0px, but is not included
 * in banner.css to avoid collisions with other themes and 
 * admin bars.
 */
body {
  margin:0px;
}
</style>

<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>
<?php

//Connect to MySQL database.
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

if (!$r) {
    echo "Could not connect to server.\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $database;

mysql_query($query);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database.");

$query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groupcodes` (`groupcode` int(10) PRIMARY KEY, `usercode` int(10))";

mysql_query($query);

$userid = "";

?>

<div id="banner">
<div id="u-header-container">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="home-link-container">
      <a id="home-link" href="http://csue.edu/">
        <span id="wordmark">U</span>
        <span id="university">UNIVERSITY</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>  
</div>
<div id="database-container">
    <header>
        <a href="index.php">
        <h4 id="logo">Computing Systems</h4>
        <h1 id="study_logo">Study</h1>
        </a>
    </header>
<div id="study">

    <form method="post" id="consent-form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

        <div class="wide-column">
            <p>
            By clicking the 'Acccept' button below, you hereby acknowledge the following:
            </p>

            <p>
            I am 18 years of age or older, live in the United States, and have a Google Drive or Dropbox account. 
            I have read this form and decided that I will participate in the project described above. 
            Its general purposes, the particulars of involvement, and possible risks and inconveniences have 
            been explained to my satisfaction. I understand that I can withdraw at any time.
            </p> 
        </div>
    <input type="text" name="email_input">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Begin Study">
    </form>

</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind providing the URL to the page and the CSS?

Comment: Or at least the index.php code :)

Comment: Besides the source code of your file, what is on the Network tab? Is it saying that the response is that HTML?

Comment: If index.php is served instead of a resource, it may be because of a 404 for instance, depending on the configuration of the web server (is it Apache?). Could you paste the requests send by Firefox (working) and Chrome (not working) so that we could check if something differs ? (full headers would be great)

Comment: try with the full path to the css files rather than the directory relative on you have here. ie /peergroup/css/bannerTest.css rather than css/bannerTest.css

Comment: wtf, changing it to /peergroup/css/bannerTest.css actually worked. I can't believe it. Does Chrome just require full paths? RamRaider, if you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the chosen answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: @RamRaider: see the above comment, which was to you. OP, please use at-usernames to notify people you are replying to them.

Comment: @user124384 - glad that's all sorted - don't worry about points etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misdiagnosed the problem. It is due to visiting different URLs to load the HTML document rather then using different browsers. You just switched browsers at the same time as you switched URLs.

Look at the URL that is being loaded in your first image:

```
http://localhost/peergroup/index.php/css/main.css
```

In Chrome you must be visiting `http://localhost/peergroup/index.php/` while in Firefox you are visiting `http://localhost/peergroup/index.php` (without a `/` at the end).

This is causing relative URLs to be computed differently.

A workaround is to use URLs that are relative to the site root (i.e. starting with a `/`).

Comment: Whoa! You're right. Thanks so much for providing a reason behind this.